# Animating a large number of simple shapes

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have a rendering system currently written in canvas. It's hitting performance issues and I'm hoping WebGL can help with some of them. Basically it comes down to a lot of simple shapes, like circles, triangles, rectangles, and lines. The problem is that a high percentage of the shapes are likely to be translated from frame to frame (see [this d3 example for an example use case, though with relatively few shapes](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045)).

I feel like I must be missing something about WebGL, because this doesn't seem like an uncommon goal, but from what I understand it's basically the worst case scenario because the vertex buffers would have to basically be replaced each frame. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: why woukf a vertex buffer have to be replaced every frame? I think you need to explain more what you are trying to do. To do what I saw in your link I'd put starting and ending points per vertex and lerp between them. http://webglsamples.org/google-io/2011/lots-of-objects-google.html

Comment: Basically the source data for the node positions is animated by JavaScript, so I somehow need to get the updated positions to the GPU every frame. It might be possible to do something like bufferSubData to only update portions of the array but I'm not sure that will really help.

Comment: Have you seen/examined any of the [three.js instancing examples](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=instancing#webgl_buffergeometry_instancing)?  Or the raw [WebGL 2.0 Samples](http://webglsamples.org/WebGL2Samples/#draw_instanced) of the same concept.

Comment: Yeah I was reading up on instancing and that seems like it might help, especially for things like circles which have a relatively high number of vertices for each instance but can be represented in the buffer by x, y, radius, and color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was me I'd calculate the starting and ending points, put them in vertex buffers, and lerp between them. Same as [*morph targets*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morph_target_animation).

Example:

```js
const numAreas = 30;
const numPointsPerArea = 100;
const maxDistFromArea = 10;
const areaWidth = 300;
const areaHeight = 150;

const endPositions = [];
for (let a = 0; a < numAreas; ++a) {
  const areaX = rand(maxDistFromArea, areaWidth - maxDistFromArea);
  const areaY = rand(maxDistFromArea, areaHeight - maxDistFromArea);;
  for (let p = 0; p < numPointsPerArea; ++p) {
    const x = areaX + rand(-maxDistFromArea, maxDistFromArea);
    const y = areaY + rand(-maxDistFromArea, maxDistFromArea);
    endPositions.push(x, y);
  }
}

const startPositions = [];
for (let a = 0; a < numAreas * numPointsPerArea; ++a) {
  startPositions.push(rand(areaWidth), rand(areaHeight));
}

function rand(min, max) {
  if (max === undefined) {
    max = min;
    min = 0;
  }
  return min + Math.random() * (max - min);
}

const vs = `
attribute vec4 startPosition;
attribute vec4 endPosition;
uniform float u_lerp;
uniform mat4 u_matrix;

void main() {
  vec4 position = mix(startPosition, endPosition, u_lerp);
  gl_Position = u_matrix * position;
  gl_PointSize = 2.0;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision mediump float;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
}
`

const m4 = twgl.m4;
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');
// compile shaders, link program, look up locations
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
// put data in vertex buffers
const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
  startPosition: { data: startPositions, numComponents: 2 },
  endPosition: { data: endPositions, numComponents: 2, },
});

const easingFunc = easingSineOut;

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;  // convert to seconds
  
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  
  // gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);

  // set uniforms
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    u_matrix: m4.ortho(0, 300, 150, 0, -1, 1),
    u_lerp: easingFunc(Math.min(1, time % 2)),
  });

  // gl.drawXXX
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo, gl.POINTS);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);

function easingSineOut(t) {
  return Math.sin(t * Math.PI * .5);
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Hopefully you get the point. It's up to you to add whatever other data you want (point per color, size per point, use a texture for points if you want some other shape than a square, or use triangles. Add similar data for lines, etc...) The important part is putting both the start and ending data and lerping between them

```
attribute vec4 startPosition;
attribute vec4 endPosition;
uniform float u_lerp;

void main() {
  vec4 position = mix(startPosition, endPosition, u_lerp);
```

Otherwise there's nothing wrong with uploading every frame via `bufferData` or `bufferSubData`. [Here's an example](http://webglsamples.org/google-io/2011/10000-objects-optimized.html) from [this talk](http://webglsamples.org/google-io/2011/index.html) updating 10000 objects where JavaScript is computing the position of the objects and updating all 210596 vertex positions and uploading the values via `bufferData` every frame.

The big difference between uploading via bufferData and canvas/svg is that with WebGL you're removing a ton from your loops. Consider

### Canvas/SVG

- for each object

  - compute position
  - call multiple draw functions

    - eg: ctx.fillStyle, ctx.begin(), ctx.arc(), ctx.fill()
    - draw functions generate points, copy to buffer (via gl.bufferData)
    - draw functions call gl.draw internally

So for 1000 objects that might be 4000 canvas api calls each of which is doing possibly a `gl.bufferData` internally, multiple `gl.drawXXX` calls and other things

### WebGL

- for each object

  - compute position
- gl.bufferData
- gl.drawXXX

In the WebGL case you still compute 1000 positions but you avoid potentially 3999 api calls and 999 calls to bufferData and replace it all with one draw call and one call to bufferData.

The Canvas and SVG APIs are not magic. They are doing the same things that you'd do manually in WebGL. The difference is they are generic so they can't optimize to the same level and they require lots of functions to produce output. Of course `ctx.fillStyle, ctx.beginPath, ctx.arc, ctx.fill` is only 4 lines of code so that's much less code then drawing a circle in WebGL but in WebGL, once you've defined the a circle you can draw more of them in 2 calls (gl.uniform, gl.draw) and those 2 calls are incredibly shallow (they aren't doing much work) where `ctx.arc` and `ctx.fill` are doing a ton of work. On top of which you can design solutions that draw 100s or 1000s of circles in a single draw call.

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you. I don't think I can use your code since I need the animation portion to be more flexible (ie using d3-force directly and then passing the resulting JS object into my renderer), but the supplemental information was invaluable. If that demo is really updating the positions in JS, I'm 100% confident webgl will not be the bottleneck in what I'm building, which is great news! I'll go ahead and move forward with updating the buffers every frame.